# C# Save object to json without property name using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json

I've a class which should be saved in json. But I want only the values of the properties to save in a list without the property names.

This is what I get at the moment:

```
{
"Data": {
  "property1": "value 1",
  "property2": "value 2",
  "property3": "value 3",
  "property4": "value 4",
  "property5": "value 5",
  }
}
```

This is what i want for example:

```
{
  "Data": [
    "value 1",
    "value 2",
    "value 3",
    "value 4",
    "value 5"
  ]
}
```

I serialize the class with the following line:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
//...
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(classInstance)
```

Does anyone know how to archive this?

EDIT:

```
public class Example
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public string property2 { get; set; }
    public string property3 { get; set; }
    public string property4 { get; set; }
    public string property5 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: use a collection from the get go.

Comment: The latter is array, you can add a property in getter of which you collect all property values and in setter - set them back. Then serialize/deserialize just that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection to get values from your `Example` class:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetPropertyValues<T>(T input)
{
    return input.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Select(p => p.GetValue(input));
}
```

now you will be able to get expected result:

```
var input = new Example
{
    property1 = "value 1",
    property2 = "value 2",
    property3 = "value 3",
    property4 = "value 4",
    property5 = "value 5",
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {Data = GetPropertyValues(input)}, Formatting.Indented);
```

`json` would be

```
{
  "Data": [
    "value 1",
    "value 2",
    "value 3",
    "value 4",
    "value 5"
  ]
}
```